# Append a string to every matching pattern starting with some characters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to append a string '_SOMETHING' to every existing string in a file starting with 'check_nrpe_aix' using awk or sed

Before :

```
define command {
        command_name    check_nrpe_aix_load
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -p $USER11$ -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -a $ARG1$ $ARG2$ ARG3$
        }

define command {
        command_name   check_nrpe_aix_cpu_stats
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -p $USER11$ -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -a $ARG1$ $ARG2$
        }
```

After :

```
define command {
        command_name    check_nrpe_aix_load_SOMESTRING
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -p $USER11$ -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -a $ARG1$ $ARG2$ ARG3$
        }

define command {
        command_name   check_nrpe_aix_cpu_stats_SOMESTRING
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -p $USER11$ -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -a $ARG1$ $ARG2$
    }
```

Comment: On SO we do encourage people to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly add so and let us know then.

Comment: `sed 's/check_nrpe_aix/\1_SOMETHING/'`

Comment: @InnocentBystander i mean the words starting with 'check_nrpe_aix' ... not the whole line

Comment: I managed to do it with :
sed 's/check_nrpe_aix[^ ]*/&_SOMETHING/' file_name
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I placed your example in a file named input.txt

```
$ cat input.txt 
define command {
        command_name    check_nrpe_aix_load
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -p $USER11$ -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -a $ARG1$              $ARG2$ ARG3$
        }

define command {
        command_name   check_nrpe_aix_cpu_stats
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -p $USER11$ -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -a $ARG1$ $ARG2$
        }
```

Now if you run :

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=""} {if ($0 ~ /check_nrpe_aix/) print $0,"_SOMESTRING";else print $0}' input.txt
```

you should get the result you expected:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS=""} {if ($0 ~ /check_nrpe_aix/) print $0,"_SOMESTRING";else print $0}' input.txt
define command {
        command_name    check_nrpe_aix_load_SOMESTRING
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -p $USER11$ -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -a $ARG1$ $ARG2$ ARG3$
        }

define command {
        command_name   check_nrpe_aix_cpu_stats_SOMESTRING
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -p $USER11$ -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -a $ARG1$ $ARG2$
        }
```

Breaking it down:

OSF is the output field separator. I set it to empty so it doesn't add a space when appending the "_SOMESTRING" to the line

The command

```
if ($0 ~ /check_nrpe_aix/) print $0,"_SOMESTRING";
```

will search for the "check_nrpe_aix" expression and print the whole line ($0) plus "_SOMESTRING" separated by OSF

The command 
    ;else print $0}

will print the whole line without alterations if it doesn't match the condition of the previous command

Comment: I've upvoted your answer for the effort, but imho awk is not the best tool for this. A simple `sed 's/.../.../'` command is all that's needed.

Comment: I agree. I guess I am just an awk fan :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\<check_nrpe_aix\S*/&_SOMETHING/g' file
```

Append `_SOMETHING` to any word beginning `check_nrpe_aix`.